# Differential equation solving circuit didn't result the right solution

Tags: operational-amplifier

According to calculations, this circuit should have solved the differential equation 25y''+ 5y' + y= (15,5)x

So when I give x= 0,1 V, y should be 1,55.But it becomes -10V. Why?

For the [ltspice file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HfqMip-d72f6y6W5-sVkhs4h7Yq_AOw2)

[image]

Comment: Circuits don't solve equations. Circuit behavior can be **described** by an equation. There's an error in the circuit, the output of U3 is shorted to the +10V supply rail.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie http://www.dummies.com/education/science/science-electronics/how-to-solve-differential-equations-using-op-amps/

Comment: @pipe OK, I see, sort of like an analog computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like U3's output is connected to the 10 V rail. You probably wanted its positive supply connected since it's left unconnected.

Comment: Yes. It now gives correct answer.

Comment: The final value may be 1.55, but the transient should be a decaying oscillation with \$\zeta=0.5\$